# C# linq to sql insert

Tags: c#, linq, linq2sql

В локальной базе данных имеется табличка `User` с полями `PersonName`, `PersonPass` и `ID(pk)`. У `ID` тип данных `uniqueidentifier` и значение по умолчанию (`newid()`). Когда я просто добавляю данные в таблицу ключ действительно уникальный создается, но при использовании вставки через форму с использованием `linq to sql insert` в базе данных в поле ключа что-то вроде *00000-000000* и при добавлении нового пользователя возникает ошибка, так как у второго пользователя в поле ключа те же самые нули. Из-за чего это происходит и как это исправить?

```
private void buttonRunReg_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext())
    {
        User sequence = (from user in db.User
                             where user.PersonName == textBox1.Text 
                             select user).SingleOrDefault();

        if (sequence==null)
        {
            if ((textBox1.Text != "") && textBox2.Text.Equals(textBox3.Text))
            {
                    User userTable = new User();
                    userTable.PersonName = textBox1.Text;
                    userTable.PersonPass = textBox2.Text;
                    db.User.InsertOnSubmit(userTable);
                    try
                    {
                        db.SubmitChanges();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                    }
                    labelExForm2.Text = "регистрация прошла успешно";
                    labelExForm2.Visible = true;

            }
            else if (!textBox2.Text.Equals(textBox3.Text))
            {
                labelExForm2.Text = "пароли не совпадают";
                labelExForm2.Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                labelExForm2.Text = "Птушка не клюет зерно";
                labelExForm2.Visible = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            labelExForm2.Text = "Имя "+textBox1.Text+" уже занято. попробуйте другое.";
            labelExForm2.Visible = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4):

В дизайнере Linq to Sql установите для столбца ID значение true в параметре Auto Generated Value.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подробнее:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb386929(v=vs.110).aspx (блок "Предупреждение явного задания значений, созданных базой данных, в Insert или Update")

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/753003/linq-to-sql-insert-sequential-guid

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1182946/auto-generate-in-linq-to-sql

Comment: Спасибо огромное.

Comment: @Anna992 Если ответ Вам помог, отметьте его, пожалуйста, как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).